# Problems with using C dll in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dll, ctypes, dllimport

I'm trying to import my own made C dll to python code. The function in the dll accepts 10x1 vector of float, return 1 float as result. This is MWE how I try to use it:

```
from ctypes import*
import numpy as np
mydll = cdll.LoadLibrary(".\Test.dll")
input=[18.1000, 1.1000, 0.2222, 0.2115, 0.0663, 0.5000, 352.0000, 0, 0, 42.0000]
input=np.transpose(input)
result=mydll.Test(input)
```

This fails with following error:

```
----> 7 result=mydll.Test(input)
ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'TypeError'>: Don't know how to convert parameter 1
```

Can you help me figuring it out? My first idea was that maybe input data does not match but it doesn't matter if I transpose or not, the error is the same.

Comment: What is the *C* function signature? Please read [\[SO\]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611011/4788546).

Comment: Use argtypes and restype to resolve this. This clue should be enough when combined with websearch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get in the habit of always specifying `.argtypes` and `.restype` for your functions.  the defaults expect integer/pointer inputs and an integer return value.  The `numpy` helper [`numpy.ctypeslib.ndpointer`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.ctypeslib.html#numpy.ctypeslib.ndpointer) can help specify the exact type and shape of the required `numpy` array.

Example C API and Python code:

**test.c**

```c
#ifdef _WIN32
#   define API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#   define API
#endif

API double Test(double* pdata) {
    double sum = 0.0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        sum += pdata[i];
    return sum;
}
```

**test.py**

```py
import ctypes as ct
import numpy as np

mydll = ct.CDLL('./test')
mydll.Test.argtypes = np.ctypeslib.ndpointer(dtype=ct.c_double, shape=(10,)),
mydll.Test.restype = ct.c_double
data = np.array([18.1000, 1.1000, 0.2222, 0.2115, 0.0663, 0.5000, 352.0000, 0, 0, 42.0000])
print(mydll.Test(data))
```

Output:

```
414.2
```